# Material UI Autocomplete Multiple - remove already selected tag from options list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

When using the [Material UI Autocomplete](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values) for multiple values, the already selected input also gets displayed in the options list in blue background color.

How can I set autocomplete to not show the already selected values in the options list ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocomplete [component](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/) provides the `filterSelectedOptions` prop, which can be used to hide the selected option(s) from the list of options.

The second autocomplete in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tags-material-demo-forked-y6pfo?file=/demo.js:787-798) created by MUI team, has that prop enabled.